# js async function executed when referenced

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm trying to reference an async function but instead it gets executed.

```
const Payment = props => {
    const [buttonAction, setButtonAction] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(some true stuff){
            // this gets executed instead of being a reference to a function
            setButtonAction(() => createSubscription(a ? b : c ));
        }
    }, [deps...]);

    const createSubscription = async (sessionId) => {
        // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React's [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) setter functions accept either:

- The data to set, or
- A function to call with the most recent version of the data (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) in the documentation) that will return the data to set

By passing a function into `setButtonAction`, you're asking React to call that function with the most recent value of `buttonAction` so you can update it.

You can't directly store functions in state like that, and there's *usually* no reason to do so (though there are edge cases).

Some alternatives:

- If you really need to store a function in state, wrap it in an object.
- Use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) or [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to reuse a function, only updating it when its dependencies change
- Keep it in a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs) instead.

Comment: useCallback is suited for the logic I'm writting. I ended up using useRef(); const buttonAction = useRef(null); SETTING buttonAction .current = () => createSubscription( a? b : c );  CALLING onClick={() => professionalButtonAction.current()} . Thanks a lot.